# Authorization Error while logging in through Google SSO

Tags: google-cloud-platform, authorization, single-sign-on, saml, developer-console

I am trying to log into a particular app(can't tell the name due to NDA signed) by clicking on **Log in with SSO**.
I am getting the following error:-

```
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
The redirect URI in the request, https://app.someapp.com.region/oauth2, does not match the 
ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update the authorized redirect URIs, visit: 
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/${your_client_id}? 
project=${your_project_number}
```

I am not sure if it's due to mis-configuration in the developer console or due to wrong redirect in the code.
Attaching the screenshot for the reference.
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUeUI.png)

Comment: Can you add any more details  about you setup ? What steps did you take to troubleshoot this ?